# C#: return the definition of a class (Java getClazz duplicate)

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to reurn a class definition to use it later for the deserialization of a json object, more or less a duplicate of the following Java function:

```
public Class<?> getClazz()
{
    return Account.class;
}
```

So far I have written this in my c# solution (Models being a folder that contains Account.cs, the file describing the Account class):

```
public Type getClass()
    {
        return Models.Account;
    }
```

The error I'm getting reads: 'Account is a Type, which is not valid in the given context.'

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: what about `.GetType()` ?

Comment: `typeof(Models.Account)` should do the trick

Comment: Folders don´t have any effect on the class´ name, but *namespaces* do. So I think your actually class-name is just `Account`, not `Models.Account`. It is common practice to reflect the filesystem-structure within the namespaces, but that´s not a must.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Models.Account` does not represent a `Type` object.

Basically, this is another one of those times where C# code can be translated "word for word" to Java and vice versa.

```
Java                           C#
-----------------------------------------------
SomeClass.class                typeof(SomeClass)
objOfSomeClass.getClass()      objOfSomeClass.GetType()
```

Which means, you can just return `typeof(Models.Account)`.

But as you can see, in C# there already exists a method that is equivalent to Java's `getClass` - `GetType`, so your method is actually unnecessary.

Side Note: `getClass` is a native method and it is definitely not implemented the way you wrote it :)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tested it yet but it seems to resolve my issues! I'm kinda new to c#, so I really appreceate the in-depth answer!